# Ionic vue plugin

Tags: vue.js, ionic4, ionic-vue

I am trying to create an ionic-vue app following [this post](https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-the-ionic-vue-beta/) but I get `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error, when I register `@ionic/vue` plugin in *main.js*.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import Ionic from '@ionic/vue'
import '@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css'

Vue.use(Ionic)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ionic/core": "^4.6.2",
    "@ionic/vue": "0.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
```

Comment: you didn't import Vue `import Vue from 'vue'`

Comment: @Dadboz I did. Sorry copy and pate typo. Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with `ionicons`. According to [this thread](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18640#issuecomment-507075212) adding `ionicons@4.5.9-1` fixes the issue.

Comment: This issue just got fixed by later versions of `ionicons` itself. It would be nice to update the answer accordingly.